# Has Nigel Farage ever responded to his "Unfinished Business" quote?

Tags: united-kingdom, brexit

One month before the [2016 Brexit referendum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2016_United_Kingdom_European_Union_membership_referendum), [Nigel Farage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nigel_Farage), who [favored Brexit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nigel_Farage#Brexit), was [quoted](https://www.mirror.co.uk/news/uk-news/nigel-farage-wants-second-referendum-7985017) arguing that a close result would leave "unfinished business":

> Farage told the Mirror: “In a 52-48 referendum this would be unfinished business by a long way. If the remain campaign win two-thirds to one-third that ends it.”

The referendum result was 52-48, but on the "leave" side of the knife-edge.

Two days after the referendum, he was [quoted arguing against another referendum](https://www.mirror.co.uk/news/uk-news/nigel-farage-says-brexit-referendum-8283500):

> But they [petition signers] were snubbed by Nigel Farage, who told the Sunday Mirror: “It’s the last thing I want to see. It’s not a game of the best of three.”

Has Farage addressed his earlier "Unfinished Business" quote?

Comment: I seem to recall Farage actually supported a second referendum (obviously in the hopes that a new vote for Brexit would settle the issue more definitively) at some point in the last 12 months or so. Don't know if he does now,

Comment: Please see my comments below. As of 2019 Feb 28 Farage is against a second referendum.

Answer (score 7):

I'm not aware that Nigel Farage was ever asked about this specific quote, but he has expressed his opinion about a second referendum a few times recently:

- He told his side to prepare for it: "When I’ve talked in the past about being worried that they may force us into a second referendum. I don’t want it anymore than you do but I am saying to you we have to face reality in the face." https://www.irishexaminer.com/breakingnews/world/nigel-farage-urges-brexiteers-to-prepare-for-second-referendum-898370.html at 2019 January 18.
- He said he is confident leave would win by a bigger margin:

  - “I suspect it will be a much bigger vote to Leave than before, because it becomes about trust. The first referendum was about are we better off or worse off, being independent, being self-governing.The second referendum will be about whether we trust our politicians, and isn’t it time we actually taught them a lesson for not listening to us first time around." https://www.express.co.uk/news/uk/1071956/nigel-farage-brexit-news-latest-vote-no-deal-second-referendum-theresa-may-date-leave-uk at 2019 Jan 14.
  - "Mr Farage told Channel 5's The Wright Stuff a fresh vote could "kill off" the Remain campaign for a generation. He later clarified his remarks saying it was the "last thing" he wanted but Leave voters had to be prepared and he was confident they would win again." https://www.bbc.com/news/uk-politics-42649214, at 2018 Jan 11.
- "Nigel Farage has told Sky News he would not vote or campaign in a second Brexit referendum if the choice was between Theresa May's deal or Remain." https://news.sky.com/story/nigel-farage-wouldnt-campaign-or-vote-in-second-brexit-referendum-11648823, at 2019 Feb 26.
- *[added after H2ONaCl's comment]* In Farage's LBC broadcast of 2019 Feb 28 Farage said a second referendum would be "an outrage" and he said "I don't see much demand for it" https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ONK654dN9a4. While the YouGov poll ending on 2019 Jan 4 has second referendum support at 41 / 36 / 22 (3-ways: support/oppose/neither; [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opinion_polling_for_the_United_Kingdom_European_Union_membership_referendum#Support_for_a_second_referendum)), he downplays support by mentioning that there is only 8% support for a second referendum in what he presented as a 5-way poll but was actually a 7-way poll ([YouGov survey results](https://d25d2506sfb94s.cloudfront.net/cumulus_uploads/document/4ovmboa1iw/Internal_190108_Brexit_web.pdf), p.3).

Comment: In Farage's LBC broadcast of 2019 Feb 28 Farage said a second referendum would be "an outrage" and he said "I don't see much demand for it". The YouGov poll ending on 2019 Jan 4 has second referendum support at 41 / 36 / 22 (3-ways: support/oppose/neither) so Farage seems disingenuous because he obviously keeps an eye on YouGov. Farage is very fond of pointing out that there is only 8% support for a second referendum in what he presented as a 5-way poll but was actually a 7-way poll.

Comment: Timestamp 8:08  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ONK654dN9a4

Comment: @H2ONaCl Thanks, I added this to my answer, hope that's ok? Also I couldn't find the results of the poll you mention, do you have a source?

Comment: The 2019 Jan 4 second referendum poll is from on Wikipedia. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opinion_polling_for_the_United_Kingdom_European_Union_membership_referendum#Post-referendum_polling I believe both polls are on the YouGov website but you need to scroll back a few weeks.

Comment: There may be newer polls but since you asked for it, here is the link to the 2019 Jan 8 result with the second referendum getting a 8% result in a 7-way poll. See page 3. https://d25d2506sfb94s.cloudfront.net/cumulus_uploads/document/4ovmboa1iw/Internal_190108_Brexit_web.pdf  Both polls are from YouGov so it seems Farage monitors YouGov.

Comment: It might be worth pointing out that in the 7 way poll linked above which Farage is said to be using to justify not having a second referendum the most popular result at 28% is to simply cancel Brexit.  The next more popular, Brexit with no deal, is significantly behind at 22%.

Answer (score 4):

A caller on Farage's show on LBC radio put this quote to him on September 3rd, 2016. Farage denied making the comment, suggesting that he had been predicting that members of the Conservative party would be irreconcilable to the result of the referendum. The show is available on YouTube ([timestamped link](https://youtu.be/q1BJS-IbmWA?t=648)) and a transcript of the exchange is below:

> **Simon:** I also believe that you said, before the referendum, that if
> the vote is close, like 52-48 on the Remain side, you wanted a second
> referendum because it wasn't conclusive enough. Because it's gone in
> your favour you've suddenly backtracked on that and you don't agree
> with it.
>
> **Farage:** Actually Simon, I said that there would be some within the
> Conservative party who I knew would be irreconcilable to this result,
> but frankly, when I hear the Scottish Nationalists talking about
> another referendum on separating from the rest of the United Kingdom,
> I think it all sounds a bit like sour grapes, and I would argue Simon,
> I would argue, that there was indeed a certainty that what we voted
> for in this referendum, we voted to take back control of our country.
> Exactly how that looks, nobody can tell you right today, just as
> nobody could tell you exactly what it would be like had we voted to
> stay in. But I don't think anyone was confused, but I respect your
> opinion if that's how you feel.